# Start browser process and pass process id to close it later

Tags: c#, process

My example looks similar to this:

```
Process.Start("http://www.webpage.com?processId=");
```

How to get process id before process starts? Or can I set some Guid as another identifier that will persist?

Comment: Do you want to pass the process-id of the browser that is showing the webpage to the website that is shown in the browser instance (would be browser-dependant) or do you want to open webpages from your application and later close all created instances?

Comment: @Michael I want to open url like this: http://webpage.com?processId=123123 where processId is id of tab where url opened.

Comment: @karaxuna int processId = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;

Answer (score 6):

```
Process p =  Process.Start("cmd.exe");
int processId = p.Id;
```

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: This is an example of how to get the id of the process that was just started.

Answer (score 1):

*not tested*

I think you should try the following:

1. Know which browser is the default browser on the target machine. I assume firefox.
2. Test if the browser is currently running. You can do that with `var instances = Process.FindByName("firefox.exe")` - you might need the full path to the local firefox installation. After that `instances` contains handles to all firefox instances that are currently running.

From here on we have three cases to cover:

1. `instances` is an empty array. This means the browser is not running. Then you start the browser with `var processHandle = Process.Start("firefox.exe")`. Then you run the following command line `$"firefox.exe -new-tab http://myurl.com/?id={processHandle.Id}"` which (hopefully) recognizes that an instance of firefox is already running and opens the page inside the existing instance. (Executing this command can also be done with Process, but you'll have to create an Process instance without starting it, specifing the arguments in [StartInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.diagnostics.process.startinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) and start it then)
2. `instances` contains exactly one entry. So all we have to do is running the same command line as in case one: `$"firefox.exe -new-tab http://myurl.com/?id={instances[0].Id}"`
3. `instances` contains multiple entries. That means that multiple firefox-windows are open. I have no solution for this. You'll have to check if the `-new-tab` option targets always the same window or not...